# .Net and MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, .net

I’m trying to setup a ASP .Net application on my hosting site but am having trouble. This site works from my workstation connecting to the GoDaddy database server but when I publish it to the server I get the following error. I have other site working on this hosting account but this is the only MySQL application. Also this is the most basic of site, I’m just trying to verify database connection, the page returns a count from a single table. I have contacted support but said it was an error with my application. I’m not sure where to look, any help would be appreciated.

Things I know

- IIS 7.0 with .Net v4 (other v4 sites working)
- This code works locally, crazy smile page

It feels like a MySQL data connector isn’t installed or the wrong version but I’m at a loss of what to do next. I have stripped the web.config to a basic .config — site still works locally but doesn’t on the GoDaddy server.

– Error Message

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not
> be installed

–Web Config, I have modified connection string with * for posting purposes

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>

<!–
   For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
–>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name=”ConnectionString” connectionString=”server=*.db.7773742.hostedresource.com;User Id=*;Persist Security Info=True;password=*;database=*”
providerName=”MySql.Data.MySqlClient” />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<customErrors mode=”Off”/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode=”Detailed” />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have added the following lines to the web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug=”true” targetFramework=”4.0″>
<assemblies>
<add assembly=”MySql.Data, Version=5.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d” />
</assemblies>
</compilation>
<customErrors mode=”Off”/>
</system.web>
```

and copied the MySQL.dll in the bin directory. Still doesn’t work.

Comment: Your Connection String does not seem correct. I don't think you can assign "*" for User ID, Password and Database. Refer to http://help.godaddy.com/article/3323 for forming MySQL Connection Strings.

Comment: ...copied the MySQL.dll in the bin directory... You mean MySql.Data.dll?